# MongoDB Constraint on datatype

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am fairly new to MongoDB so I am trying to read up on as much as possible. At the moment I am looking into how constrains are handled.

From what I can understand there is no real constrains since it's schemaless. However there is a way to simulate constrains by using indexes and partial indexes.

This seems fine but how do i do constrains against datatypes?
Say I have a document person and I wanna make sure no one types a string value into the social security field that should only contain integers.

Can I handle this or do i have to use some library/third party program for this? (Mongoose??)
I am developing with the MongoDB C# drive and could probably solve this by making a restriction in my application, but I am just wondering if there is some other/better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 3.2 provides the capability to validate documents during updates and insertions. Validation rules are specified on a per-collection basis using the validator option, which takes a document that specifies the validation rules or expressions.

Please see [Document Validation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document-validation/)